# Write query for this example

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with below data,I want to write a query that give me id and the number of days that have connection.

For example for id 1 give me 2 times (2016-09-20 , 2016-09-22)

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you ask. Do you need the number of days or the dates? And what if the last row's EndTime was Sept 25? By the way, you should show what you have tried so far, StackOverflow is not a homework solver place. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't post the sample table data as image.. And one another thing, for id = 1 if StartTime is 2016-09-20 and EndTime 2016-09-20, then it should count as 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT convert(date, startTime)) as noOfDays
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are checking the days only based in the `startdate` column,use the below query.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cast (StartTime as date)) DaysCount
FROM YourTable
Where ID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this

```
Select id,TotalCount=Count(id) from YourTable group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Al though the question is not very clear, I think you are trying to get the total number of connection days for every ID taking into consideration multiple connection per day (all counted as one connection). Also connection may span several days (depending on the EndTime) in which case these number of days should be counted as well.

Try this:

```
declare @tt table(id int, StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime)
insert into @tt values
 (1, '2016-09-20 13:01', '2016-09-20 13:30')
,(1, '2016-09-20 14:20', '2016-09-20 16:09')
,(1, '2016-09-20 17:20', '2016-09-20 17:51')
,(1, '2016-09-22 23:20', '2016-09-22 23:40')

,(2, '2016-09-20 14:20', '2016-09-20 16:09')
,(2, '2016-09-20 16:01', '2016-09-20 16:09')

,(3, '2016-09-20 14:20', '2016-09-20 14:56')
,(3, '2016-09-23 19:20', '2016-09-23 20:09')

,(4, '2016-09-20 22:20', '2016-09-20 23:00')

select * from @tt

;with cte1 as
(
    select ID, convert(Date, StartTime) as StartDate
    , convert(Date, max(EndTime)) as EndDate
    from @tt 
    group by id, convert(Date, StartTime)
), 
cte2 as 
(
    select *, DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate) +1 as DaysCount 
    from cte1
)
select id, sum(DaysCount) as DaysCount 
from cte2
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,count(distinct(dbo.GetDateInt(StartTime))) NoofDays from table_name group by id
```

Note: *this query performed in sql server 2012 and `getDateInt()` is database function. That returns date only like 2016-09-23.*